# How to get Angular Material Slider to appear after the label?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am looking at the docks for Angular Material's [Sliders](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api#MatSlideToggle).  By default, the slider appears, and the label follows it like so:

[image: slider example]

However, I would like the text 'Auto Approve?' to appear prior to the slider option.  According to the docs, I need to use the Input module for Angular which I am not really familiar with.  Based on what I have read, I should be doing this in my component:

```
 import {Matslidetogglemodule} from '@angular/material'
    ... 

   @Component({
       ...
   }) export class MyComponent{

      @Input()
      labelPosition: string = 'before'

   }
```

that `@input` should be changing the label to appear prior to the slider, but it does not.  Am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `@Input` in your component.

Just create e.g `labelPosition` variable in your component and set it to `'before'`.

And then in your template on your mat-slide-toogle tag add this variable as this `[labelPosition]="labelPosition"`

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egavaw?embed=1&file=app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.ts).